# Struggling to Updating the value using (connection.query(update...)) when customer select the product using - NodeJS/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, database-design

I am looking to decrease the quantity of stock(`stockQuantity`) each time customer purchases in `main_product_info`.

I am trying to use the below code but it looks like its not working, i am a new to `DB` so not sure if i am using the correct code.

Also as in the below code i am directly updating the `quantity` against the `productNumner` or shall i use join(i have seen few post around but couldn't undersrtand) and including the `main_product_sub_category`(as it has the primary key ) as well, just want to understand the correct way of doing it.

`Error:` **stockQuantity** is not defined.

Any suggestions please.

```
 connection.query("UPDATE main_product_info SET stockQuantity=? WHERE main_product_info.producNumber=?", [stockQuantity - 1, checkQuantity], function (err, result) {} 
// here  i am looking to decrese stockQuantity by 1
```

-`main_product_info`   [image: Updating the Quantity]

-`Snippet` of code using show create table,

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE main_Products_category;
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| main_Products_category | CREATE TABLE `main_products_category` (
  `productId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productCategory` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE main_products_sub_category;
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| main_products_sub_category | CREATE TABLE `main_products_sub_category` (
  `main_Products_sub_category_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `main_Products_sub_category_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_Products_category_productId` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`main_Products_sub_category_id`),
  KEY `fk_main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_category1_idx` (`main_Products_category_productId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_category1` FOREIGN KEY (`main_Products_category_productId`) REFERENCES `main_products_category` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE main_product_info;
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| main_product_info | CREATE TABLE `main_product_info` (
  `producInfoId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` mediumtext,
  `stockQuantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `producNumber` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_sub_category_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`producInfoId`),
  KEY `fk_main_Product_Info_main_Products_sub_category1_idx` (`main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_sub_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_main_Product_Info_main_Products_sub_category1` FOREIGN KEY (`main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_sub_category_id`) REFERENCES `main_products_sub_category` (`main_Products_sub_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it in mysql direcly without parameter

```
 connection.query("UPDATE main_product_info SET stockQuantity= stockQuantity - 1 WHERE main_product_info.producNumber=?", [checkQuantity], function (err, result) {} 
// here  i am looking to decrese stockQuantity by 1
```

Comment: i am trying the same query with a variable but it doesnt seems to be working, ```let actaul_Bought_Items = req.body[0].quantity;  connection.query("UPDATE main_product_info SET stockQuantity=stockQuantity-actaul_Bought_Items WHERE main_product_info.producNumber=?", [checkQuantity], function (.... ``` I am not getting any error but it is not working for sure, any suggestion/pointers please

Comment: this would only work if actaul_Bought_Items  is part of main_product_info , but in your post i don't see none with the column name, if you changed your database, please open a new question

Comment: Thanks i have managed to do it. i just used the quantity as length and used a for loop and doing the same connection.query to get the result...